# Find command prints numbers infront of result

Tags: linux, command

Am using the following "find" command to extract some files,

```
find /lag/cnnf/ -maxdepth 3 -newer ./start ! -newer ./end | grep -nri abc | egrep '([^0-9]45[^0-9])' | grep -nri "db.tar.gz" >> sample.txt
```

My output in sample.txt is

```
5:175:/lag/cnnf/abc/45/r-01.bac.db.tar.gz
20:190:/lag/cnnf/abc/45/r-01.bac.db.tar.gz
```

what should i do to get only,

```
/lag/cnnf/abc/45/r-01.bac.db.tar.gz
/lag/cnnf/abc/45/r-01.bac.db.tar.gz
```

without the random numbers in front of it and what those numbers actually mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `grep` which is printing the numbers, not `find`. Remove the `-n` option from the `grep` commands and the numbers will disappear.

```
find /lag/cnnf/ -maxdepth 3 -newer ./start ! -newer ./end | grep -ri abc | egrep '([^0-9]45[^0-9])' | grep -ri "db.tar.gz" >> sample.txt
```

Also it looks like unnecessary overhead to use 3 `grep` statements, one should be enough, or even the find command itself can do the filtering job. Would need to know your input data to say more